# What happened to the jars of oil without a seal?

Tags: chanuka

Are there any sources that say what happened to the jars of olive oil without the seal in the temple? Did they throw it out,sell it, eat it,etc...?

If not then would there be a reason why they couldn't use(sell,eat,burn the oil at home,etc) the oil?

Comment: Because you have to use perfectly pure oil for the lighting of the menorah

Comment: I'll edit my questions, I meant utilizing it for other things such as  eating,selling, etc..

Comment: Presumably if it was set aside for service in the Temple that would make it 'Hekdesh' i.e. of a consecrated status and to benefit from such a thing would make someone chayav me'ilah refer to Vayikra 5:15–16 here - https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.5.15-16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: I found that ["anything which is fit for the altar, is never released from the altar" (Men. 101a; Maim. Yad, Arakhin 5).](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/hekdesh). Does this mean that they would have to permanently have to store the oil?

Comment: @DavidWarshawsky, that applies only to things that were "consecrated in a service vessel" (Rambam, Hil. Issurei Mizbe'ach 6:5). The oil wasn't in such a vessel, otherwise it would anyway have been disqualified by being left in it overnight (linah). So yes, presumably they could have bought the oil back from the Temple and used it for other purposes.